# prefix sylius product show url with locale

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am using sylius v0.18. I want to prefix locale with product show urls.

```
sylius_core:
routing:
    %sylius.model.product.class%:
        field: slug
        prefix: /p
        defaults:
            controller: sylius.controller.product:detailsAction
            repository: sylius.repository.product
            sylius:
                template: SyliusWebBundle:Frontend/Product:show.html.twig
                criteria: {slug: $slug}
                permission: false
```

I can use a static word as the prefix in this configuration. but It does not work with _locale. `prefix: /{_locale}/p`

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, by overiding getRouteCollectionForRequest method in Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Routing\RouteProvider class with the following configuration.

```
sylius_core:
routing:
    %sylius.model.product.class%:
        field: slug
        prefix: /{_locale}/p
        defaults:
            controller: sylius.controller.product:detailsAction
            repository: sylius.repository.product
            sylius:
                template: SyliusWebBundle:Frontend/Product:show.html.twig
                criteria: {slug: $slug}
                permission: false
```

```
parameters:
    sylius.route_provider.class: App\AppBundle\Routing\Provider\RouteProvider
```

```
    class RouteProvider extends BaseProvider
    {

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getRouteCollectionForRequest(Request $request)
        {
        //Overide this method to match the url with _locale
        }
```